# Merging specific nodes and adding up attributes in XSLT from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

it's my first time using XSL and i have a hard task to do.

I would like to merge and add specific nodes from my XML.

For Example:

XML:

```
<Root>
  <Result>ok</Result>
  <Type>SingleObject</Type>
  <Head>
    <DocumentLines>
      <line0>
        <LineNum>0</LineNum>
        <ItemCode>A1234</ItemCode>
        <Dscription>Article1</Dscription>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      </line0>
      <line1>
        <LineNum>1</LineNum>
        <ItemCode>B4321</ItemCode>
        <Dscription>Article2</Dscription>
        <Quantity>6</Quantity>
      </line1>
      <line2>
        <LineNum>2</LineNum>
        <ItemCode>A789</ItemCode>
        <Dscription>Article3</Dscription>
        <Quantity>8</Quantity>
      </line2>
      <line3>
        <LineNum>3</LineNum>
        <ItemCode>A1234</ItemCode>
        <Dscription>Article1</Dscription>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      </line3>
    </DocumentLines>
  </Head>
</Root>
```

Based off of the ItemCode i would like to merge line 0 and line 3 and add the Quantity together like this:

```
<Document_Lines>
  <row>
    <LineNum>0</LineNum>
    <ItemCode>A1234</ItemCode>
    <Dscription>Article1</Dscription>
    <Quantity>10</Quantity>
  </row>
  <row>
    <LineNum>1</LineNum>
    <ItemCode>B4321</ItemCode>
    <Dscription>Article2</Dscription>
    <Quantity>6</Quantity>
  </row>
  <row>
    <LineNum>2</LineNum>
    <ItemCode>A789</ItemCode>
    <Dscription>Article3</Dscription>
    <Quantity>8</Quantity>
  </row>
</Document_Lines>
```

My XSL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

        <Document_Lines>
          <xsl:for-each select="/Root/Head/DocumentLines/*">
            <xsl:variable name="index" select="1"/>
            <row>
                <LineNum><xsl:value-of select="LineNum[$index]" /></LineNum>
                <ItemCode>  <xsl:value-of select="ItemCode[$index]" /> </ItemCode>
                <Dscription><xsl:value-of select="Dscription[$index]" /></Dscription>
                <Quantity><xsl:value-of select="Quantity[$index]" /></Quantity>
            </row>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Document_Lines>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It gets all the Lines and shows them correctly but i dont really know how to progress further from here. Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ordered output in XSLT-1.0, you have to apply the [*Muenchian Grouping*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Muenchian+Grouping) method. There are many examples for this approach on SO.

Applied to your personal situation, the code could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="lines" match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'line')]" use="ItemCode" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Document_Lines>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Root/Head/DocumentLines/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('lines',ItemCode))]">
            <row>
                <LineNum><xsl:value-of select="LineNum" /></LineNum>
                <ItemCode><xsl:value-of select="ItemCode" /> </ItemCode>
                <Description><xsl:value-of select="Dscription" /></Description>
                <Quantity><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('lines',ItemCode)/Quantity)" /></Quantity>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Document_Lines>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The *Muenchian Grouping* consists of two parts:

1. The `xsl:key name="values" ...`
2. The `generate-id()=key(...)`

Both parts together let you group the `line?` elements the way you want.
**The output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document_Lines>
  <row>
    <LineNum>0</LineNum>
    <ItemCode>A1234</ItemCode>
    <Description>Article1</Description>
    <Quantity>10</Quantity>
  </row>
  <row>
    <LineNum>1</LineNum>
    <ItemCode>B4321</ItemCode>
    <Description>Article2</Description>
    <Quantity>6</Quantity>
  </row>
  <row>
    <LineNum>2</LineNum>
    <ItemCode>A789</ItemCode>
    <Description>Article3</Description>
    <Quantity>8</Quantity>
  </row>
</Document_Lines>
```

---

An improved XSLT-2.0 solution could be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Document_Lines>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/Root/Head/DocumentLines/*[starts-with(local-name(),'line')]" group-by="ItemCode">
            <row>
                <xsl:copy-of select="LineNum, ItemCode, Dscription" />
                <Quantity><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Quantity)" /></Quantity>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Document_Lines>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is the same.**

Comment: @DawnDevelop It is easier in XSLT 2.0 because you have an specific instruction for this [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)

Comment: @DawnDevelop: Yes. You could simplify the code by using XSLT-2.0's function `xsl:for-each-group`.

Comment: @DawnDevelop: I added an XSLT-2.0 solution to the answer.

Comment: @zx485 looks way cleaner and easier. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: To make it even shorter and cleaner or easier you could replace the reconstruction of the first three elements of the `row` inside of the `for-each-group` with `<xsl:copy-of select="LineNum, ItemCode, Dscription"/>`.